# Redirect domain to www, but on subdomain do not use www

Tags: 8, redirection

I have a multilanguage website. The main language is English and the second language is Spanish.

I need to have all the traffic using this domains:

- English domain: www.example.com
- Spanish domain: es.example.com

If I use the .htaccess rules from Drupal, I can redirect all the traffic to www, but it includes the Spanish traffic too. Or I can remove www to use es.example.com, but again, it would redirect the English traffic to use example.com (without www).

I have tried a lot of .htaccess combinations but I finish in a worst situation that is redirecting the Spanish traffic to the Encglish URL, so... I need to know what rules can I use to have these redirections:

- example.com to www.example.com
- www.es.example.com to es.example.com

Answer (score 1):

These rules must be included in Drupal's .htaccess file, **before** the *RewriteBase /* line.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.es\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://es.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```